ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'box.exceptions'
from box.exceptions import BoxValueError

Results in an ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'box.exceptions'.
How can i resolve this error?
I tried `pip install --upgrade box.
But still got the Error message.
(box is a python module)

What happened when you used that pip command?

Are you sure you installed the correct package?  The unfortunately named box package is brand new, with it's first release on pypi.org on November 21, 2024.   What you probably wanted was the package python-box, which gives you advanced dictionaries with dot notation access.  There are 100+ projects on pypi with 'box' in the name, so you need to make sure you use the install command for the one you actually want.

Where did that import statement come from?  I mean did you write it yourself from scratch, or were you following an example?  If the latter, can you give a link to the example?

Another possibility is that your main script itself is named box.py.

I would recommend running 'pip show python-box (or box)' to see if the package was initially installed correctly, that way it will tell you if the box module needs reinstallation -- that may be why the upgrade command did not work.
It will also be useful to double check your environment to make sure that the environment where you run the code is the same one where the package is installed. If you are using a virtual environment, activate it before running the code

This is very likely not the cause of the error.  The exception specifically refers to box.exceptions, therefore the top-level box module was found, but it did not contain a submodule named exceptions.  As @nigh_anxiety commented above, this is probably because they installed the wrong package altogether, because it had a similar name (box instead of python-box).
